# AForge Fourier transform

Tags: c#, fft, aforge

How to use this method:

```
public static void DFT (Complex[] data, Direction direction)
```

if my input array is `short[] samples`? I can easly convert `short` to `double` to put this value to `Complex` struct. But this struct has two field `Im` and `Re`. So, one of these values will be my sample value right? What is the second value? Sample number?

Please help me to solve this problem, because I will not sleep today.

Comment: Complex number has two components, Imaginary (Im) and Real (Re). Your sample value most probably be the Real component.

Comment: I know what is an complex number, just don't understand how this function (DFT) work. Anyway I'm starting to test it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should fill the `real` part of each `Complex` value with your sample data, i.e. using LINQ:

```
complexSamples = samples.Select(sample => new Complex((double)sample, 0.0)).ToArray();
```

After having performed the `DFT` your `complexSamples` will contain non-zero imaginary components (`Im` non-zero). It then depends on what your subsequent actions are whether or not you need to access these imaginary components.

Maybe it is also a good idea to read a little more on [DFT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform) and [complex numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number) on Wikipedia...

Comment: So the output Im values will represents frequency spectrum?

Comment: Actually, provided you perform a forward transform, the frequency spectrum is represented by the complex components as a whole. It depends on what you want to do with your image, but if you want to apply a low pass filter you do the forward transform, set the higher index complex components to zero and then perform an inverse transform. The `Re` part that you receive after completed inverse transform will then be your low-pass filtered image. There is an intuitive tutorial [here](http://cns-alumni.bu.edu/~slehar/fourier/fourier.html).